# Удаление просмотренного фрагмента из ViewPager

Tags: android-viewpager, android

Имеется *viewpager* который содержит в себе *N*-ое количество фрагментов. Как возможно удалять просмотренные (предыдущие) фрагменты? К примеру стартовало приложение с показа одного фрагмента в *viewpager*, далее пользователь перелистывает вперед. После этого мне необходимо чтобы перелистывание назад не было возможным - т.е. удалить предыдущий фрагмент. Прошу помочь - в каком направлении копать

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант на `ViewPager` повесить `setOnPageChangeListener()` и, когда перешли на следующий фрагмент, удалять предыдущий (в адаптере сделать метод на удаление).

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position >= 1) {
                mViewPagerAdapter.remove(position - 1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
});
```

Comment: Только небольшое замечание, необходимо добавить ещё обработчик ошибок в строке **mViewPagerAdapter.remove(position - 1);** дабы застроховаться